# How can I get an ACCESS token using MSAL in python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I cannot seem to figure out how to acquire an access token using MSAL. I’ve spend time reading the source code and Microsoft documentation to no avail. I’d like to use the PublicClientApplication to acquire the token. Even when running proof of concepts with the QuickStarts using ConfidentialClientApplication I seem to only get an ID_Token not an access token.
Ultimately I’m trying to build a desktop/mobile app and want to be able to use MSAL for id token claims and access tokens for access to APIs. Also worth mentioning I want to implement this using AAD B2C Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your access use the `acquire_token_silent` or `acquire_token_interactive` methods of the `PublicClientApplication` class.

Below is an example, replace the needed variables with your own.

```
import msal

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    "your_client_id", 
    authority="https://yourtenant.b2clogin.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signup_signin_policy",
    client_credential=None
)

scopes = ["https://yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/api/read"]

result = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes=scopes)

print(result["access_token"])
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Does this use the authorization code flow? When running i can’t seem to get it to work with that authority, I had to use login online Microsoft.com/}b2ctenantID}

Comment: Yes, it it use the authorization code flow by default

Comment: Thanks, any idea the difference between the login.Microsoftonline.com/{tenantID} endpoint and the {tenantName}.b2clogin.{tenantName}.onMicrosoft.com/{policy}?  I can’t seem to get any tokens using this endpoint but the documentation points me here.

Comment: you welcome :) Yes, login.Microsoftonline.com/{tenantID} is the Azure Active Directory (AAD) endpoint the other {tenantName}.b2clogin.{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}  is the Azure AD B2C endpoint

Answer (score 4):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplication?view=msal-dotnet-latest):

```
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

cid = "53f3ed37d4aeac"
csecret = "AFK8MY-weud6cqP7jsvAJIojaq-"
tid = "72f981db47"
auth = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tid}"

app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=cid,
    client_credential=csecret,
    authority=auth
)
s = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=s)
a = result.get("access_token")
print(a)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Here `csecret` is client secret

`cid`  is client id

`tid` is tenant id

Comment: Thanks for the help! Have you had similar results with the PublicClientApplication class? Or the other endpoint https://yourtenant.b2clogin.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signup_signin_policy? I’m also running into an issue with a user I created that uses gmail for local account, when the window pops up it tell me I need to add it as an external identity first and give me an error.

Comment: No never tried that, But i am glad you have got the answer. For other issues open a new question.